# So how do I return the correct RecyclerView.ViewHolder

Tags: android, kotlin

At one point this was OK but it the compiler is now griping at the null return value. I'm not sure how to set this up either get rid of the null, return the correct value or make the return value optional. Any advice on how to get this up and running appreciated. Have found code online but it says they way I have it coded is valid.

```
       override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        if(viewType==1) {
            val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.bus_list_row, parent, false)

            v.bus_url.setOnClickListener(object: View.OnClickListener {
                override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
                    Toast.makeText(
                            v.context,
                            "|" + v.bus_url.text + "|",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
            })
            return RowViewHolder(v)
        }

        if(viewType==0){
            val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.bus_list_section, parent, false)
            /*v.setOnClickListener(object:View.OnClickListener{
                override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
                    Toast.makeText(
                            v.context,
                            "|" + "test"+ "|",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
            })*/
            return SectionViewHolder(v)
        }
        return null
    }
```

Comment: what are the viewType values that are being received by the method?

Comment: declare RecyclerView.ViewHolder as Nullable.    RecyclerView.ViewHolder?

Comment: @DominikWuttke ---- tried that...what is was originally.... says not a subtype of overriden in android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's trim your code down a bit to make it easier to discuss:

> ```
> override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
>     if(viewType==1) {
>         // ...
>         return RowViewHolder(v)
>     }
>     if(viewType==0){
>         // ...
>         return SectionViewHolder(v)
>     }
>     return null
> }
> ```

I'm guessing based on this that you have a corresponding `getItemViewType()` method, and that the only possible values to return from this are `0` and `1`. If I'm right, the correct thing to do is to change the `return null` in your `onCreateViewHolder()` to `throw AssertionError()`.

The logic here is that you, a human, know more about the system and what's possible than the compiler does. The compiler only knows that if `viewType` isn't 0 or 1, you're going to return null and null is not allowed. But as a human you know that `viewType` can only ever be 0 or 1. The right way to reconcile these two things is to throw an error. Doing so has the following benefits:

- Satisfies the compiler
- Avoids your having to write code to handle an impossible situation
- Provides safety against changing `getItemViewType()` at some point in the future but forgetting to also update `onCreateViewHolder()` (you'll get a crash with a very obvious error)

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    if(viewType==1) {
        // ...
        return RowViewHolder(v)
    }
    if(viewType==0){
        // ...
        return SectionViewHolder(v)
    }
    throw AssertionError("impossible viewType: $viewType")
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ben-p this was concise and very helpful. Interesting that about 8 months ago when I was last looking at this it was OK code.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return `null` from `onCreateViewHolder` method. You have to either return default view holder or throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

The returnvalue  of `OnCreateViewHolder` can't be 
    `null` and a `ViewHolder` Needs a `View` which can't be `null`.

You can create an empty layout inflate it and return an empty `ViewHolder` with the empty layout as Parameter.